# how to have an IntegerField in a form for a DecimalField in the model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to do the following:

```
class AmountInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    amount = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('amount',)
```

For my model field:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

This is so that values that show in my text input are round as opposed to showing decimal places.

The problem is that decimal places still show.

It only accepts the number `60` for example as input value.  However when it shows the form instance of the field, it shows `60.00`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @madzohan What are you saying the solution is?

Comment: forget it, I was inattentive) specify custom widget for this field and in that widget override render method

Comment: @madzohan Do you know of an example of that or where it is in the docs?  From a few tries it seems an integerfield doesn't have a render method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Django field is not Django widget,  default widget for [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) and for [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) is [`TextInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput).

And from [this note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) your declaration overrides default behaviour of `amount` field. But data stored in [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type not `int` so if you want represent it in `int` you should do smth like this:

```
int(Decimal())
```

Or read [`Decimal docs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) and set custom rounding.

**2)** At this step you need smth to specify your custom rendering, so there are number of variation how you can do it (at this moment I remember two of them):

**2.1)** Simple one - override initial data in ModelForm init:

```
class AmountInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('amount',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AmountInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        amount_initial = self.initial.get('amount')
        if amount_initial:
            self.initial['amount'] = int(amount_initial)
```

**2.2)** If you need custom representation in fancy widget you can override [`TextInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) ([look at the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/984a57a9c9cba44fde61e21c08996dc678f13e81/django/forms/widgets.py#L258)) and specify it in your `class Meta` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) :

```
class YourCustomWidget(TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
        if value != '':
            # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
            custom_value = int(value)
            final_attrs['value'] = force_text(self._format_value(custom_value))

        # here you can customise output html
        return format_html('<input{0} />', flatatt(final_attrs))

class AmountInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('amount',)
        widgets = {
            'amount': YourCustomWidget(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative 2022 answer

Usage: if you enter `60` in the creation form, form redirects you to update form and displays `60` in the field (not `60.00`). In the database, the amount column shows `0.6`. The database field is `decimal` type.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AmountCreateView, AmountUpdateView

app_name = 'customers'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AmountCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', AmountUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse


class Customer(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("customers:update", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**widgets.py**

```
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
import decimal


class CustomWidget(NumberInput):

    def format_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
            # it should return this if everything's OK
            return str(int(decimal.Decimal(value) * 100))
        return super().format_value(value)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Customer
from .widgets import CustomWidget
import decimal
from django.utils import formats
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CustomIntegerField(forms.IntegerField):
    widget = CustomWidget

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None
        if self.localize:
            value = formats.sanitize_separators(value)
        value = str(value).strip()
        try:
            value = decimal.Decimal(value) / 100
        except decimal.DecimalException:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
        return value

class AmountInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amount = CustomIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('amount',)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, UpdateView
from .forms import AmountInfoForm
from .models import Customer

class AmountCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = AmountInfoForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()


class AmountUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = AmountInfoForm
    model = Customer
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```